# Secureboot: grub can be loaded, but the bzImage has a "Invalid Signature"

Tags: security

I want to make a bootable emergency USB-stick that automatically repartitions my system and unpacks a rootfs to the hard disk, installs the bootloader, etc.

I compiled my own kernel and created my own initrd with various scripts.
this works very well. only booting from an USB-stick causes problems when secureboot is active.

to work around the problem I took an official Ubuntu livecd and copied all the content like `isolinux/ EFI/*` and so on, I changed all grub-configuration-boot-entrys to my kernel and my initrd. So I think the bootloader should be secureboot capable.

i set the following parameters in grub.cfg and built a new iso:

```
set check_signatures=no
```

if secureboot is disabled, the system boots correctly.
if secureboot is active, the bootloader can be loaded. so the secureboot is done? but then the process aborts with the following error:

```
invalid signature: /boot/bzImage
```

although `set check_signatures=no` is set.

Does anyone have an idea?

Is there no other way than to sign my kernel and distribute the keys across all systems? - can I distribute the key via ssh without direct access to the hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved with signed-shim bootloader, free to download